# Isomorphism of projective varieties and coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field.

Let $f: \mathbb{P}^1(K) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2(K)$ be a morphism given by $$f([x_1:x_2])=[x_1^2:x_1x_2:x_2^2].$$

(a) Are $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ and $f(\mathbb{P}^1(K))$ isomorphic as projective varieties?

(b) Are the rings $\dfrac{K[X,Y]}{I_P(\mathbb{P}^1(K))}$ and $\dfrac{K[X,Y,Z]}{I_P(f(\mathbb{P}^1(K)))}$ isomorphic?

My attempt:

So for the first question, we want to show that $f$ is a morphism that has an inverse.

$f$ is a morphism since for $P=[x:y] \in \mathbb{P}^1(K)$, we can write $f(P)=(f_0(P), f_1(P), f_2(P))$ where $f_0=X^2, f_1=XY, f_2=Y^2 \in K[\mathbb{P}^1(K)]$ are homogeneous. Moreover, $\mathbb{P}^1(K) \subset \mbox{dom } f$.

Now, I want to find an inverse. I'm not really sure how to compute it, but my guess is for any $[x:y:z] \in \mathbb{P}^2(K)$,with $x \neq 0$, $f^{-1}([x:y:z])=[x:y]$. It will follow that if $x_1 \neq 0$, $f^{-1}([x_1^2:x_1x_2:x_2^2])=[x_1^2:x_1x_2]=[x_1:x_2]$. If $x=0$, it will follow that $y=0$. We have the point $[0:0:1]$ so $f^{-1}([0:0:1])=[0:1]$. I am not sure for the other cases.

For the second question, I observed that $f(\mathbb{P}^1(K)) =V(Y^2-XZ)$ where $V(Y^2-XZ)$ is the zero locus of $g=Y^2-XZ$. We can show that $g$ is irreducible in $K[X,Y,Z]$ so

$$\dfrac{K[X,Y,Z]}{I_P(f(\mathbb{P}^1(K)))}=\dfrac{K[X,Y,Z]}{I_P(V(Y^2-XZ))}=\dfrac{K[X,Y,Z]}{(Y^2-XZ)}$$. Meanwhile,

$\dfrac{K[X,Y]}{I_P(\mathbb{P}^1(K))}=  \dfrac{K[X,Y]}{\{0\}} \cong K[X,Y].$

Thus, this problem is reduced to showing if $$K[X,Y] \cong \dfrac{K[X,Y,Z]}{(Y^2-XZ)}.$$ But these two rings are not isomorphic since the latter is not a UFD.

Are my thoughts correct? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You mean are $\Bbb{P}^1(K)$ and $f(\Bbb{P}^1(K))$ isomorphic. It is a birational map, so find the inverse and check if it is a morphism (given locally by a non-vanishing regular map). Also I'm a bit inconfortable to call $K[x_1,x_2]$ the coordinate ring of $\Bbb{P}^1(K)$, it is clearly not the same as the coordinate ring of an affine variety.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. That was the definition given to us in our class. Would you mind to explain the coordinate ring for projective varieties?

Comment: The idea is that there is something analogous to the coordinate ring of affine varieties : it is the sheaf of regular functions, for $\Bbb{P^1(C)}$ it means gluing $\Bbb{C}[z]$ and $\Bbb{C}[1/z]$ in a space where we can extract all the information.

Comment: Given that the projective varieties are isomorphic in this case, does it follow that the coordinate rings will now be isomorphic?

Comment: To the OP: you still have a typo hanging around in your post that you need to address - part (a) of the question still says $\Bbb P^2(K)$ when it should say $\Bbb P^1$. This ruins your attempt at (a) because you're not solving the right problem. For part (b), note that the question is only asking you about the coordinate rings which should be much easier (isomorphisms of rings are things you ought to be able to get a handle on). Your first move should be to write down the definition of each of these rings and compute.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, I already edited my post. I'm just wondering if it will follow that the coordinate rings will be isomorphic, because in the affine case, an isomorphism between varities induces an isomorphism between the coordinate rings.

Comment: There's a reason the author of this exercise is asking you this question. I'll be happy to help you once you've edited your post with your own efforts in determining these coordinate algebras.

Comment: @KReiser I'm back. Please check my edited post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work in the post is correct. One easier way to write down an inverse morphism (which has the benefit of being more obviously a morphism) is as follows: on the affine patch in $\Bbb P^2$ given by $X\neq 0$, the inverse morphism can be defined by $[1:y:y^2]\mapsto [1:y]$, and on the affine patch given by $Z\neq 0$, the inverse morphism can be given as $[x^2:x:1]\mapsto [x:1]$. These maps are clearly regular and agree everywhere they're both defined, and their domain of definition is the whole of the image of $\Bbb P^1$.

Comment: Can you explain the part where $Z \neq 0$? Why is the form of the point $[x^2:x:1]?$

Comment: If a point of the form $[x_1^2:x_1x_2:x_2^2]$ has $Z\neq 0$, then we can divide all three entries by $Z=x_2^2$ to get a point of the form $[\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2}:\frac{x_1}{x_2}:1]$, which is exactly of the form $[x^2:x:1]$ for $x=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MashedPotato If this resolves your question, please consider accepting the answer by  clicking the checkmark to the left (you should also consider doing this to some of your other posts - I checked, and you have never accepted an answer!).

Comment: Done. I didn't know that was a thing. Forgive my noobness.